# What is the win32 equivalent for mac?

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, winapi

The below link shows examples on how the Windows API works:

[Module 1. Your First Windows Program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409.aspx)

I am quite interested in how the Mac API looks like.

After doing some reading, I read a lot of things like XCode (Environment), Cocoa Framework, etc.  However, I dont see any information about something like the Win32 API.

Doesn't Apple have a low level C API that is not based on Obective-C but just plain old C?

Comment: OS X implements POSIX, the portable operating system interface. You might want to look for that.

Comment: Developing GUI in plain C is terrible. Win32 API is an example for this. By contrast, Cocoa with Objective-C is a very elegant way for developing GUI, and is as powerful as Win32 (on their respective platforms). Microsoft's WinForms is easier, but is less powerful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your link points to a tutorial for the GUI components of Windows. In that case, the equivalent for OS X is indeed the Cocoa framework, which consists of the Foundation and AppKit libraries, which are Objective-C libraries.

Cocoa's control drawing is entirely local to the application. Therefore, the only way to build applications using controls is with Objective-C. Nothing stops you from building a C API on top of that; similar tactics have been used to build libraries like Qt or bindings to languages like Python and Ruby.

There is no plain C GUI API in OS X. There are low-level APIs (part of the Quartz graphics framework, aka the Core Graphics API) for dealing with the window manager to open the top-level windows, but these are either very complicated or completely undocumented. And even then, you'd be responsible for doing all the controls and input handling yourself. **Update** Some of the basic facilities that applications build on top of are also available through C APIs, namely Core Foundation, Core Graphics, Core Text, and Grand Central Dispatch. But these are still not enough to use Cocoa; Cocoa is just built on top of them.

There is also the Carbon API, which is a C API, but was intended for transitioning pre-OS X applications to OS X and is thus not suitable for new application development. In fact, I'm not even sure it is even supported anymore.

So you have two options if you want to write a GUI program for OS X in plain C:

- find a wrapper library
- give up and learn Objective-C, which sits on top of plain C anyway

If online tutorials, including Apple's official ones, don't suit you, the Big Nerd Ranch books on Cocoa development are good. Note that their beginner-oriented books are transitioning to the Swift language, but they have a separate book dedicated to teaching Objective-C as well.

You'll also need to know that OS X applications almost exclusively design their user interfaces using a graphical designer called Interface Builder, akin to the form designers in Visual Studio. With the Windows API, you can still get away with doing things by code, and a lot of people do so; with OS X, doing everything programmatically is difficult (but still possible).

Comment: *There are low-level APIs (part of the Quartz graphics framework, aka the Core Graphics API) for dealing with the window manager to open the top-level windows, but these are either very complicated or completely undocumented.*
That's what I want to know.

Comment: *but still possible* Any example?